# How do pass data binary (file data )as well as other parameters in json via curl

Tags: java, linux, rest, jpa, curl

Have a table with an id and a clob field in database.
Need is to implement a Post service to persist data for this table for which an entity is designed with @lob for (CLOB column String java type) and @id(ID) in db.
I have designed a rest service which takes input in the format below-
{
id: input_id,
data: clob_data
}

How do we pass id and the contents of the file to get stored via rest and curl.
Or if there is a better way to implement open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the ID from the POST body to the URL.  This would allow the POST body to just be the file content which would then allow a simple curl command like this:

```
curl -d @file_to_post https://<your_server>/path/to/service/<input_id>
```